# Sql: insert subquery result to column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with several columns. I want to create a new column from an existing one. Say column "A" is text, I want to insert into column "B" the left 10 characters of column "A".

I do:

```
insert into table (B) select left(A, 10) from table;
```

However, I want this to be aligned with column "A" not as new rows, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want this to be aligned with column "A" not as new rows

Insert adds new rows. Since you need to update existing ones, use `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET B = LEFT(A, 10)
```

Comment: That was so simple. Thank you!

Comment: `ERROR:  cannot use column references in default expression` + I don't think that PostgreSQL supports computed/generated columns yet.

Comment: @lad2025 Right, Postgres doesn't allow it. Thank you!